# Updating a legend name in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript, legend, nvd3.js

Currently, I'm on d3. When I'm trying to update a legend name in d3 it's updating the name but leaving a space after removing the old one.

[image]

[image]

If you see the images I updated the test formula 2 to test formula 4, d3 removed the test formula 2 and updated it to test formula 4 but leaving a space between test formula 1 and 3. I posted my code for reference. data is the data shown on the graph.

```
svgData = svg.select('g.data').selectAll('g.datum').data data, (d)-> d.key
newData = svgData.enter()
  .append 'g'
  .classed 'datum', true
legends = newData.append 'g'
  .classed 'legend-entry', true
  .attr 'opacity', 1
  .on 'click', hidden.toggle
legends.append 'circle'
  .attr 'r', 2
  .attr 'cx', 1
  .attr 'stroke-width', 1
  .attr 'fill', (d)-> scales.color(d.key)
  .attr 'stroke', (d)-> scales.color(d.key)
legends.append 'text'
  .attr 'x', 5
  .attr 'y', 2.5
  .attr 'font-size', 7
  .text (d)-> d.key
legends = svg.selectAll('g.legend-entry')
try
 entryWidth = _.memoize((d)-> d3.select(d).node().getBBox().width)
 legends.attr 'transform',  (d, i)->"translate(#{width-
  2.5*d3.sum(legends[0].slice(0, i+1), entryWidth)} #{gutters.top-10}) scale(2)"
catch err
  console.warn 'problem placing legends; '+err.message`
```